# mongoose-auth exceptions

Tags: mongoose

I get the following exception when I add mongoose-auth to my server.js and I am not sure what the issue is. Can someone help

```
  exports.helpExpress = everyauth.helpExpress.bind(everyauth);
} has no method 'middleware'
    at HTTPServer.<anonymous> (/home/x/x/settings.js:44:26)
    at HTTPServer.configure (/home/x/x/node_modules/express/lib/http.js:543:61)
    at bootApplication (/home/x/x/settings.js:27:7)
    at Object.boot (/home/x/x/settings.js:21:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/x/x/app.js:4:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of express, mongoose and mongoose-auth?  If not, what versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this thread https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth/issues/20 ( tsabolov's  comment at the end) .

app.use(mongooseAuth.middleware()) has to be used after declaring the Schema plugin.